# How to get the name of a document in Alfresco with SQL?

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

How to retrieve the name of a document from the Alfresco database (PostgreSQL)? I'm trying to get a list of documents created by a given user, e.g. admin, from a starting date, e.g. 2015-05-03:

```
SELECT child.child_node_name, node.audit_created
FROM alf_child_assoc child, alf_node node, alf_node_properties prop, alf_qname qname
WHERE child.child_node_id = node.id
AND node.id = prop.node_id
AND prop.qname_id = qname.id
AND qname.local_name = 'content'
AND node.audit_creator = 'admin'
AND node.audit_created > '2015-05-03'
ORDER BY node.audit_created
```

How do I get actual documents and not all content items?
Because now it also displays full node references and I just want the **human readable name of a document**. Any suggestions?

By the way, I'm working on the back-end (Repository), not on Share. And I'm using Alfresco 5.0.1.

Comment: I would suggest to add a namespace, cause property `content` could come from different namespaces (if you added custom types). To do so you need to join with `alf_namespace` on `uri`. In you case add this to `where`: `and qname.ns_id = alf_namespace.id
and alf_namespace.uri = 'http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0'`

Comment: My I ask why on earth you want to do this? :)

Comment: Yes, sure. Real life example: in the project I am working on we have two sites: one for personnel documents and second for finance documents. Since it's a different (custom) types of documents they (documents) have different namespaces: `http://www.mycomp.com/personnel/content/1.0` and `http://www.mycomp.com/finance/content/1.0`. So obviously it make sense to filter documents by types. [Here](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html) you can find more information about custom types.

Comment: So, why not run a simple script in alfresco with search.luceneSearch method http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/API-JS-luceneSearch.html and extract all the info you need in a log file or a webscript with a json object to read from? I'm not sure why people would interrogate the Alfresco db when you have Solr and Lucene on top to ask for all the data in the repository.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit my coment: here you can achieve the same using alfresco JS: @cm\:creator:"admin" and @cm\:created:"[2003\-12\-16T00:00:00 TO MAX]" and TYPE:"cm:content" put this in the luceneSearch method and you're pretty much set :)

Comment: I totally agree with you, if you want to get any information about your Alfresco instance webscripts is the way. But sometimes it is easier to get it from database - another real life example: monitoring Alfresco with [AppDynamics](https://www.appdynamics.com/). To get number of documents in repo it's much easier to make it work with SQL query rather than with JSON response from webscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the other anwsers I created this query:

```
SELECT string_value AS document_name, audit_created AS creation_date
FROM alf_node node
INNER JOIN alf_node_properties ON (id=node_id)
INNER JOIN alf_qname ON (qname_id=alf_qname.id)
WHERE ns_id IN
(SELECT ns.id FROM alf_namespace AS ns
WHERE ns.uri='http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0')
AND local_name='name'
AND audit_creator = 'admin'
AND audit_created > '2015-05-06'
ORDER BY audit_created;
```

This way you don't have to know the qname_id.

Thank you Sam, Gagravarr and streetturtle.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated**

So here is SQL you need to use, this one for `cm:content` type:

```
select nd.audit_creator as creator, 
       np.string_value as document_name, 
       nd.audit_created as created_on
  from alf_node as nd, alf_node_properties as np, 
       alf_namespace ns, alf_qname qn, alf_qname qn1
 where nd.id=np.node_id
   and qn.ns_id = ns.id
   and nd.type_qname_id = qn.id
   and ns.uri = 'http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0'
   and qn.local_name = 'content'
   and qn1.ns_id = ns.id
   and np.qname_id = qn1.id
   and qn1.local_name = 'name'
   and nd.audit_created > '2015-05-06 14:59:00';
```

It will return human readable document name, username of creator and date when this document was created.

And if you have some custom type of document, let's say `ep:content` with namespace `http://www.mycomp.com/model/epersonnel/1.0` this query will do the work:

```
select nd.audit_creator as creator, 
       np.string_value as document_name, 
       nd.audit_created as created_on
  from alf_node as nd, alf_node_properties as np, 
       alf_namespace ns, alf_namespace ns1, alf_qname qn, alf_qname qn1
 where nd.id=np.node_id
   and qn.ns_id = ns.id
   and nd.type_qname_id = qn.id
   and ns.uri = 'http://www.mycomp.com/model/epersonnel/1.0'
   and qn.local_name = 'content'
   and ns1.uri = 'http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0'
   and np.qname_id = qn1.id
   and qn1.ns_id = ns1.id
   and qn1.local_name = 'name'
   and nd.audit_created > '2015-05-06 14:59:00';
```

Comment: It works, but I should note that my version uses qname_id 28.

Answer (score 3):

I ran this SQL script to find the equivalent qname id for this property

```
select * from alf_qname where local_name='name';
```

I got 2 rows with id 21 and 29 but figured out the interesting one is 29.

```
SELECT * FROM alf_node_properties where qname_id = '29';
```

You will get name for any node not only files.

You can find useful queries http://streetturtle.ninja/2015/05/01/usefule-alfresco-queries/

Hope this help

Good luck, 
Sam

Comment: Those queries in the link are very useful indeed.

Comment: Link has changed: http://pavelmakhov.com/2015/05/usefule-alfresco-queries

Answer (score 1):

In Alfresco, the name of a document is a property of of type `cm:name` / `http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0:name`

So, first up, find the ID of that qname. It may vary between Alfresco installs, depending on the order things got added during setup, but it will be constant for an Alfresco repository. Query is:

```
=> select * from alf_qname where ns_id IN 
     (select ns.id from alf_namespace as ns 
     where ns.uri='http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0') 
   and local_name='name';
 id | version | ns_id | local_name 
----+---------+-------+------------
 29 |       0 |     6 | name
(1 row)
```

Now, search for documents by name, using the ID from there:

```
select uuid, string_value AS name from alf_node 
   inner join alf_node_properties on (id=node_id) 
   where qname_id = 29;
```

That will give you all the node UUIDs (main part of the noderef) along with their names.

Add more node filters as required!

Comment: I don't need the UUIDs and the query still shows those noderefs as a name too, can those be filtered too?