# How to make this SQL query for Alfresco shorter?

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

How the SQL query I made for Alfresco shorter?

```
SELECT string_value AS document_name, audit_created AS creation_date
FROM alf_node node
INNER JOIN alf_node_properties ON (id=node_id)
INNER JOIN alf_qname ON (qname_id=alf_qname.id)
WHERE ns_id IN
(SELECT ns.id FROM alf_namespace AS ns
WHERE ns.uri='http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0')
AND local_name='name'
AND audit_creator = 'admin'
AND audit_created > '2015-05-06'
ORDER BY audit_created;
```

[This is where the query came from.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121317/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-document-in-alfresco-with-sql)

Comment: What's not user friendly about this query and what needs to be improved ?

Comment: A user friendly query? What are the probllems with the current one?

Comment: "more user friendly query" makes no sense to me

Comment: I meant: how to make this query shorter actually, I'll update the Q.

Comment: Add aliases to all tables and to all column references, not only for readability.

Comment: You can replace `INNER JOIN` with `JOIN` that will make it shorter and you don't need the parentheses around the join conditions. Removing them will also make it shorter. But you should really prefix every column with the proper table (alias) - that will make the statement more robust and readable - much more important that being "shorter"

Comment: you may replace the subselect on the ns_id with the id in your repo but this is the query you need to get the name.